# Is it possible to automate definitions given with TagSetDelayed?

Tags: packages, code-generation, automation

I am using the following two lines of code relatively frequently

```
f/:Plus[f[x_], f[y_], z___]:=f[x+y]+z
f/:Times[c_, f[x_]]:=f[c x]
```

and I was wondering if it is possible to automate the process.

What I have in mind, is to supply a list of heads to a function and the function will make definitions similar to those presented above, for every head in the list.

The idea is to have a package that defines a bunch of heads that behave like `f` above and exports them to the user without having to show the user how the behavior is implemented.

I'm interested in avoiding possible side-effects from the automation process, if there are any.

So, to sum up, is it possible to automate the two `TagSetDelayed` definitions presented above, in a package that safely exports the heads exhibiting the same behaviour as `f`, without major side-effects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
Scan[
  Function[head,
    head /: Plus[head[x_], head[y_], z___] := head[x + y] + z;
    head /: Times[c_, head[x_]] := head[c x]
  ],
  {f, g, h}
]
```

Comment: if it works in a package without any weird side effects, sure it does

Comment: @joka I use it myself quite regularly. [Here](https://github.com/ssmit1986/DualNumbers/blob/main/DualNumbers/Kernel/UpValues.wl), for example.